# Simple sql script doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I created simple sql script and tried to execute it in phpMyAdmin. It gives error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{ id INT, firstName VARCHAR(15), lastName VARCHAR(15), email VARCHAR(20)' at line 1
```

Hereis the code:

```
CREATE TABLE phoneList{id INT,
    firstName VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
    lastName VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
    email VARCHAR( 20 ) ,
    phone VARCHAR( 15 ) };
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{`s must be replaced with `(` and `}`s with `)`

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE phoneList(
    id INT,
    firstName VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
    lastName VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
    email VARCHAR( 20 ) ,
    phone VARCHAR( 15 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the { } in your code.
You need to use ( ) instead.

```
CREATE TABLE phoneList(id INT,
firstName VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
lastName VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
email VARCHAR( 20 ) ,
phone VARCHAR( 15 ) );
```

Hope this helps!

Kai :-)